# Angular - Whether to use a tag or button

Tags: angular, button, anchor

I got this part of code from someone. It is part of an Angular app. I can't contact him anymore.

There are two buttons in each row of a table - **Edit** and **Delete**. Why would he use an `<a>` tag for one and a `<button>` for another? I can use either `<a>` tags or `<buttons>` for both right?

```html
<td>
  <a routerLink="edit/{{account.id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-1">Edit</a>
  <button (click)="deleteAccount(account.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-delete-account" [disabled]="account.isDeleting">Delete</button>
</td>
```

Comment: My best guess is he used `<a>` to use the `routerLink` property. But it could also be used with the `<button>` tag. And I'd say it's better to use `<button>` since you're clearly assigning the CSS selectors `btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-1`.

Comment: Without seeing the app in action I'm guessing that clicking on "Edit" redirects you to another view, while clicking on "Delete" leaves you on the same page. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because with anchor you are calling some route with edit fields and with button you are requesting some service for deletion of the account. Pretty much same behavior different implementation.

For example instead of anchor you can create button with click event to call some service who will create some request for the wanted result, in your case edit functionality.

Now on your question. Its always better to use routerLink with anchor tag instead of doing it with buttons since its much simpler but in case if you want to call some GET, POST etc. you will definitely need button with click event in order to call some service who will do the job.

I hope this answers you question :).

Happy coding